# How to Generate RDLC Report for Grouping Header Before Data?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I have a  reportviewer RDLC report and I want to move the `group data` on top before the other content. [image]

**Here is the output.**

[image]

I want to put the `school name` parameter before the other data. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Tablix` you can right click on your detail row header and select `Add Group` > `Parent Group`:

- Group by: `school_name`
- Add group header